# Finding presence of substring within a string in BASH

Tags: bash, shell, grep, substring

I have a script that is trying to find the presence of a given string inside a file of arbitrary text.

I've settled on something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="myfile.txt"
for j in `cat blacklist.txt`; do
  echo Searching for $j...
  unset match
  match=`grep -i -m1 -o "$j" $file`
  if [ $match ]; then
    echo "Match: $match"
 fi
done
```

Blacklist.txt contains lines of potential matches, like so:

```
matchthis
"match this too"
thisisasingleword
"This is multiple words"
```

myfile.txt could be something like:

```
I would matchthis if I could match things with grep.  I really wish I could. 
When I ask it to match this too, it fails to matchthis.  It should match this too - right?
```

If I run this at a bash prompt, like so:

```
j="match this too"
grep -i -m1 -o "$j" myfile.txt
```

...I get "match this too".

However, when the batch file runs, despite the variables being set correctly (verified via echo lines), it never greps properly and returns nothing.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't

```
grep -owF -f blacklist.txt myfile.txt
```

instead of writing an inefficient loop, do what you want?

Comment: No; that returned a whole lot of stuff that didn't match.

Comment: Right. This also matches substrings inside larger strings. I have modified my solution. However, my solution would still match the word _bar_, if your input file contains `foo;bar;baz`. Is this what you want, or should there be no match in this case?

Comment: This still seems like a superior solution conceptually. If something doesn't work exactly like you expect, probably experiment with the `grep` flags, or clarify what exactly is wrong, perhaps in a new question specifically about this problem with a proper [mre]

Answer (score 0):

1. 

With this:

```
if [ $match ]; then
```

you are passing random arguments to `test`. This is not how you properly check for variable net being empty. Use `test -n`:

```
if [ -n "$match" ]; then
```

You might also use `grep`'s exit code instead:

```
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
```

2. 

`for ... in X` splits X at spaces by default, and you are expecting the script to match whole lines.
Define `IFS` properly:

```
IFS='
'
for j in `cat blacklist.txt`; do
```

3. 

`blacklist.txt` contains `"match this too"` with quotes, and it is read like this by `for` loop and matched literally.

`j="match this too"` does not cause `j` variable to contain quotes.
`j='"match this too"'` does, and then it will not match.

Since whole lines are read properly from the `blacklist.txt` file now, you can probably remove quotes from that file.

Script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
file="myfile.txt"
IFS='
'
for j in `cat blacklist.txt`; do
  echo Searching for $j...
  unset match
  match=`grep -i -m1 -o "$j" "$file"`
  if [ -n "$match" ]; then
    echo "Match: $match"
  fi
done
```

Alternative to the `for ... in ...` loop (no `IFS=` needed):

```sh
while read; do
    j="$REPLY"
    ...
done < 'blacklist.txt'
```

Comment: I'd avoid using `for ... in` to read files; even with a modified `IFS`, it's still not respecting quotes or escapes, and it'll try to expand anything that looks like a filename wildcard (which can have completely silly results). Also, if you change `IFS`, you should always set it back afterward to avoid weird problems later.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I tried to only fix the original code, not to modify it. Still this `IFS=...;for ... in ...` is a working solution and to my knowledge it is trustworthy. The alternative is to use `while read` loop with the file contents passed to its input. I will modify the answer to include that.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="myfile.txt"

while IFS= read -r j; do
    j=${j#\"}; j=${j%\"}                        # remove surrounding double quotes
    echo "Searching for $j..."

    match=$(grep -i -m1 -o "$j" "$file")
    if (( $? == 0 )); then                      # if match
        echo "Match: $match"                    # then print it
    fi
done < blacklist.txt
```

Output:

```
Searching for matchthis...
Match: matchthis
Searching for match this too...
Match: match this too
match this too
Searching for thisisasingleword...
Searching for This is multiple words...
```

Answer (score 0):

I wound up abandoning grep entirely and using sed instead.

```
match=`sed -n "s/.*\($j\).*/\1/p" $file
```

Works well, and I was able to use unquoted multiple word phrases in the blacklist file.

Comment: Reading one search phrase at a time and repeatedly scanning the entire input file is a horrible antipattern. You can probably refactor this to a single `sed` script which searches for all your search phrases in one go. I have several answers demonstrating how to do this in more detail; maybe [search for `sed -f` in conjunction with my user name.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=tripleee+%22sed+-f%22+site%3Astackoverflow.com&t=brave&ia=web)